# How to open multiple websockets on the same port

Tags: apache, websocket, server, port

So i'm using the Ratchet Websockets in my Laravel application and i'm wondering, if it's possible to open multiple websocket servers on the same server and the same port? Basically I want to have my apache and 2 seperate socket servers on the same machine and on the port 80 and access them with different sub domains, for example mypage.com, socket1.mypage.com, socket2.mypage.com

Comment: Acc to me , <ip address+ port >form a unique combo for socket identification ,be it client or sever. So i don't think running multiple server on same ip + port is going to work .

Comment: In the ratchet documentation it's mentioned that accessing socket on the same port as a web server is possible by some kind of port forwarding

Comment: interesting ...:) can you point me the link ?

Comment: http://socketo.me/docs/deploy#serverconfiguration

Comment: you can do this by reverse proxying using apache or nginx by making your web server listen to same ip+port and then redirect to different paths :
for example :  Nginx listening at 0.0.0.0:7000 and then requests routes to 
-may be /PathA and listens at 0.0.0.0:7001
-maybe  /PathB and listens at 0.0.0.0:7002
-maybe  /PathC and listens at 0.0.0.0:7003
This is just an assumption , i havnt done it practically myself.